# Can VFA and CFA be interchanged?

Tags: voltage, operational-amplifier

If for example you have an inverting circuit(as the one in the image), can you change the opamp from a VFA to CFA and the circuit would work the same?  And the LM741 is a VFA or a CFA?[image]

Answer (score 1):

- The LM741 unit is an amplifier with voltage-feedback (VFA).
- If you replace the VFA with a Current Feedback Amplifier (CFA), the behaviour will be not "the same". However, most probable the maximum closed loop gain will be the same - but the usable bandwidth certainly will change as well as the slewing behaviour (slew rate, large signal bandwidth). More than that, it is required that the feedback resistor must not be lower than a certain minimum value which is specified by the manufacturer (some hundreds of Ohms). This is because this value alone defines the amount of feedback (and not the resistive voltage divider as is the case for a VFA).

Comment: "this [Rf] value alone defines the amount of feedback" seems like an indicator that the gain won't stay the same for most circuits if you blindly replace a VFA with a CFA.

Comment: I don`t think so. In both cases (VFA and CFA) the closed-loop gain is (primarily) determined by the resistor RATIO (-R2/R1) or (1+R2/R1), respectively. However, the amount of feedback - and therefore, the loop gain expression - is different in both cases. As a consequence, the closed-loop gain in case of CFA is available in a nearly constant bandwidth.